# How to configure nvidia-cuda-mps-control so that there can be multiple users running on the same system

Tags: cuda

I have, for example, a 4 GPU system. I would like to be able to have 2 users each using MPS on 2 GPUs. In reading the nvidia documentation it looks like I would set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to specify what GPUs are visible to the nvidia-cuda-mps-control daemon (and then to the server process). Is it then true I would need two instances of the control daemon, each able to see 2 different GPUs in order to have a different user on each pair of GPUs? How would I start 2 instances of nvidia-cuda-mps-control on the same system, can I specify that each use a different port or something?

Comment: Limit your post to a single question please. Also, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: As a long shot I've tried having a single nvidia-cuda-mps-control starting multiple nvidia-cuda-mps-server's with different uid's, the first one starts but when the second is submitted both servers exit(!?)

I've tried starting a second nvidia-cuda-mps-control with a different CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES but still get the "An instance of this daemon is already running" message.

It looks like I really need to be able to start multiple instances of nvidia-cuda-mps-control to get multiple nvidia-cuda-mps-server's for different uid's on different GPUs. Any suggestions or different approaches to try?

Comment: Comments are not for the questions. The edit button is for improving your question following suggestions or questions made in the comments. I suggest you read the Help section to better learn how this site works and why it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use containers for different users, and set env (export CUDA_MPS_ACTIVE_THREAD_PERCENTAGE) for a user in his container.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CUDA MPS LOG and PIPE directories for each daemon.